# What happens when you 'redirect_to' an instance var in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm diving into RoR and as I'm going through the tutorials, scaffolds, and docs, I'm coming across some code that confuses me.  For example, I just read up on the 'redirect_to' method, but the guide I read didn't cover the example of redirecting to an instance var, such as the code that is generated in a typical scaffold...

```
# POST /articles
  # POST /articles.xml
  def create
    @article = Article.new(params[:article])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Article was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article, :status => :created, :location => @article }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @article.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In the statement `format.html { redirect_to(@article, :notice => 'Article was successfully created.') }`, the code is redirecting to the instance var `article`, which causes a 'redirect_to' the `show` method in the current controller.  Why does this cause it to redirect to the show method?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why does this cause it to redirect to the show method?*
Because if you don't specify particular action, Rails assumes you want to 'show' object. If you have another action in mind, try

```
redirect_to :action => :do_something, :id => @article
```

Comment: Thanks, Nikita!  I assume then that means that 'redirect_to(@article)' is equivalent to 'redirect_to(:action => :show, id => @article)' ?

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe Looks like. There's not a lot of choice for framework, since _resources :articles_ generates only 7 routes and _show_ seems like the most logical option.

Comment: I found a special case where Rails is a little more clever; if the implied `:id` is `nil` Rails will fall back on the `:index` route.